ScalaFX type mismatch witch JavaFX namespace
While compiling the MainStageDemo from scalafx.org I get this error message:
None of the overloaded alternatives of method <== in trait Property with types
 (v:
  scalafx.beans.value.ObservableValue[? <: javafx.scene.paint.Paint, ?
     <: javafx.scene.paint.Paint]
): Unit
 (v: javafx.beans².value².ObservableValue²[? <: javafx.scene.paint.Paint]): Unit
match arguments (scalafx.beans.binding.ObjectBinding[J])

where:    J                is a type variable with constraint >: javafx.scene.paint.Color |
  (scalafx.scene².paint².Color.Red : scalafx.scene².paint².Color²) and <: Object
          ObservableValue  is a trait in package scalafx.beans.value
          ObservableValue² is a trait in package javafx.beans².value²
          beans            is a package in package scalafx
          beans²           is a package in package javafx
          value            is a package in package scalafx.beans
          value²           is a package in package javafx.beans²

          fill <== when(hover) choose Green otherwise Red

The example in question is:
import scalafx.Includes._
import scalafx.application.JFXApp3
import scalafx.scene.Scene
import scalafx.scene.paint.Color._
import scalafx.scene.shape.Rectangle

object HelloStageDemo extends JFXApp3 {

  override def start(): Unit = {
    stage = new JFXApp3.PrimaryStage {
      title.value = "Hello Stage"
      width = 600
      height = 450
      scene = new Scene {
        fill = LightGreen
        content = new Rectangle {
          x = 25
          y = 40
          width = 100
          height = 100
          fill <== when(hover) choose Green otherwise Red
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

sbt version is 1.10.0 and contents of build.sbt are:

ThisBuild / version := "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"

ThisBuild / scalaVersion := "3.4.2"

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .settings(
    name := "test"
  )

libraryDependencies += "org.scalafx" %% "scalafx" % "22.0.0-R33"

The project was created using IntellijIDEA and openjdk-22. My guess is that this is a namespace problem, but I don't have enough experience using Scala to say for sure.

Not sure if it will help, but try to use stable versions. Like Scala 3.3.3 and Java 17.

I was able to run the example provided using scala 2.13.14 with JDK 17, 21 and 22. It seems like there is some problem in scala 3 when the compiler try to infer the type parameter required by the method choose. So, to make it work, the type parameter must be explicit
// add this import
import javafx.scene.paint

// replace `fill <== when...` for the following
fill <== when(hover).choose[paint.Color](Green) otherwise Red


This is a known problem. The issue documentation: First example doesn't compile #373 was opened on Jan 27, 2022 and it's not solved yet, but there are some suggestions on how to fix it. The one I suggested above is one of them, another one was suggested by philwalk where you need to change how you import the Color class.
// replace
import scalafx.scene.paint.Color._

// for
import javafx.scene.paint.Color.{GREEN => Green, RED => Red, LIGHTGREEN => LightGreen}


Scala 3 changed the type inference algorithm, so maybe choose was designed to work with the Scala 2 version. Opening a bug report in both the ScalaFX and the Scala 3 repos seem like a good idea.

Thanks for the suggestion @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez. I was about to do it, but then, I found the issue documentation: First example doesn't compile #373 and stills open. There are a couple of suggestions about how to solve this problem. One of them is the fix I wrote in my answer.

Updated my answer with the link to the reported issue

A lot of ScalaFX "magic" is based on implicit conversions between JavaFX and ScalaFX types. It gets challenging when type parameters are involved. Scala 3 deals with implicit conversion, sometimes, differently than Scala 2. In the original problematic line, the fill property type parameter is JavaFX type, but Red and Green are ScalaFX types
fill <== when(hover) choose Green otherwise Red

That got resolved Scala 2 but not in Scala 3.
The simples workaround for Scala 3 is to refer to delegates (underlaying JavaFX values), for each color constant, so Scala does not need to use implicit conversions for type parameters of fill property:
fill <== when (hover) choose Green otherwise Red.delegate

It is simple because no other changes are needed, no additional imports or type aliases are needed, only ScalaFX types are used in the imports. Note that it is sufficient to do it inside the otherwise.
